# Custom Session id is not being remembered

Tags: php, session, get

I'm creating a script with sessions but the server doesn't remember the settings.
It's using a variable id so that might be the problem but how can I fix this?

Here is the code:

URL Example: http://domain.eu/isloggedin.php?code={0} <- Windows Application will fill this in.

Login:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();
$code = $_GET['code'];
$lstring = $code . "-CONFIG";
$_SESSION[$lstring] = "True";
?>
```

GET:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();
$code = $_GET['code'];
$lstring = $code . "-CONFIG";
if (isset($_SESSION[$lstring])){
echo "True";
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Regards,

Daniël

Comment: Make sure if you call both script the get variable isset. Also add error reporting to see if you have any errors: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`

Comment: @Rizier123 I have checked and the GET variable is set and when I insert your script it doesn't display any errors. So I still don't know what's wrong. Is there any other cause for this issue?

Comment: Please show us your **full** script also explain when and how you call your script (+ how the url looks like)

Comment: I'll update the post